Multiple Web Apps with own subdomain, sharing domain, behind Cloudflare
I am writing a script that will create a new Web App in Azure. It will be used by essentially non-technical personnel to create Web Apps on demand, probably a few times a day. One of the script parameters is the name of the new Web App.
Assuming my company's domain is "mycompany.com", and the script is given the name "name1", than the new Web App must have url
"name1.mycompany.com"
Other Web Apps could be at
"xyz.mycompany.com",
"secondname.mycompany.com",
etc.
Additionally, all the Web Apps will sit behind Cloudflare for DDOS protection etc.
This means that to my domain registrar, I will specify Cloudflare's nameservers for mycompany.com instead of the Azure nameservers.
This way, traffic for mycompany.com goes to Cloudflare instead of directly to the Web Apps.
I know how to configure the DNS records in Cloudflare so traffic to name1.mycompany.com goes to the IP address of the Web App with name "name1".
However,

people using the script will not have access to Cloudflare,
I don't have time to update Cloudflare myself each time somebody uses the script to create a new Web App,
I could use the Cloudflare API to create a new DNS record, but that is one more thing that can easily fail.

Essentially, I want Cloudflare to pass all traffic for mycompany.com to Azure (after DDOS protection, etc.), and let my Web Apps pick up the requests meant for them.
How should I configure Cloudflare and Azure to make this happen?

"This way, traffic for mycompany.com goes to Cloudflare instead of directly to the Web Apps." - Doing this will introduce additional latency, make troubleshooting more difficult, and make custom-domain verification for Azure App Services far more error-prone and bothersome - but what problems will you solve (rather than introduce) by using CloudFlare?

The only wildcard routing that CloudFlare supports is many-to-one. Ie:
*.yourdomain.com >> yourapp.azurewebsites.net
...or...
*.yourdomain.com >> 193.54.12.16
...(not practical since App Servixe IPs are not static).
There are no dynamic proxy backend selector capabilities that will suit your requirement of not having to touch CloudFlare each time an app is deployed with a new domain name.
Azure Front Door and Azure Application Gateway are not suitable in this instance either. Observers should trust me on that, or waste their time at their own peril.
Other solutions, like nginx, IIS URL rewrite, and other powerful routing, balancing and rewriting thingys just take too long to setup and maintain.
Your best option is to configure Virtual Applications or Virtual Directories in App Service. This will result in having a single App Service in a single plan, with a single domain name. This switches routing reliance from domain name to URI path. Inherent to this come a couple of constraints.

All applications will share the resources of a single plan. But this is ok if you're happy to scale your plan up when resources become contended, or you use autoscaling on a suitable pricing tier.
The required runtime for execution of the App must be consistent across all applications, since they will be sharing a single App Service instance.

Steps

Create Web App

Decide upon a suitable initial plan (you'll need the standard or premium tier for auto-scale-out, but manual scale up or down is available for all tiers)
Make note of your domain name.


Configure CloudFlare

You will need to create the following entry in CloudFlare DNS
Adjust the Name and inappropriately named IPv4 Address accordingly






Type
Name
IPv4 Address
Proxy Status




CNAME
corporateapps.company.com
corporateapps.azurewebsites.net
Proxy




Deploy Applications

Assuming you are using a PowerShell script, and Windows App Service:



# Get the current Web App configuration
$resourceGroupName = "MyResourceGroup"
$webAppName = "CorporateApplications"
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webAppName

# Set up the virtual application
$virtualAppPath = "myapp1"
$virtualApp = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Models.PSVirtualApplication
$virtualApp.VirtualPath = "/$virtualAppPath"
$virtualApp.PhysicalPath = "site\wwwroot\$virtualAppPath"
# Set preload to disabled to reduce memory consumption. Set to enabled to negate startup latency at expense of memory
$virtualApp.PreloadEnabled = $false

# Apply the virtual application configuration
$webApp.SiteConfig.VirtualApplications.Add($virtualApp)
Set-AzWebApp -WebApp $webApp

# Get the publishing profile for the Web App
$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webAppName

# Deploy the ZIP file to the virtual application path using the Kudu API
$zipDeployUrl = "https://$($webAppName).scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?path=$virtualAppPath"
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new($publishingProfile.PublishProfile[0].UserName, $publishingProfile.PublishProfile[0].UserPWD)

$webClient.UploadFile($zipDeployUrl, "POST", $zipPath)

Test thoroughly, and after you should have a scripted solution which uses CloudFlare for all your apps without having to use the CF API.
As an aside, if ever you want the solution to be fully native to Azure, you may want to investigate using Azure Front Door instead of CloudFlare for App protection. It has very similar capabilities, but you'd need to think carefully how you automate provisioning because you don't want "non-technical" staff members having the ability to provision (or deprovision, for that matter) entry points to Azure.
